# Is there a popup soft keyboard in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

As a noob I wrote an app with lots of layout screens and it worked OK in emulation but when I ran it on my Droid Incredible the soft keyboard popping up changed the layout of a LinearLayout I was using - shoving some elements aside and changing the height of others!   I fixed it by adding *android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan”*  to the Activity element of the manifest but I really would have preferred to discover this problem in emulation and not on a real phone.

So, is there a popup soft keyboard in the Emulator and if so how do I invoke it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is, you only need to click on an EditText box with your mouse and it will open.

Comment: I just tried this with a 2.2 platform AVD and a soft NUMERIC keyboard popped up.   The number keys were in European characters; some of the other surrounding keys had characters that looked like Korean and Chinese (or Japanese?  Hanji and Kanji look similar to me).    Plus, it didn't exhibit the behavior of messing up the LinearLayout that the alpha keyboard on my phone did.

Comment: if you touch and hold the text box you will get a context menu to allow you to select which IME installed on the OS to use.  Also, if the text box is declared in the XML file to be numeric the keyboard will show numbers by default.

Comment: Thanks.  When I did that it let me select the input method and I found that it was defaulting to the Japanese IME!  I have no idea why it would do that.  But when I switched to Android Keyboard all it worked.  (it still doesn't mess up the layout like the on in my phone does but that's for another thread)  Thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on ICS as it just goes to the copy menu

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You can go to the emulator's edit page, do not choose the "Use handware keyboard".

Comment: As of Apr 2016 on Android Studio 2.0 MacBook Pro -- this is the proper way of doing it.  The emulator defaults to hardware keyboard( e.g. laptop).