# How can I make the Android emulator show the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm debugging an issue with the soft keyboard display not displaying when it should.  However, I don't have a device handy for testing.  The problem is that **the emulator *never* shows the soft keyboard**.

Some skins have a keyboard constantly displayed on the right, some don't, but none that I've tried so far has ever shown a keyboard on the device screen.

Is there some setting that I missed?

Comment: Per this link:  Just click on an Edit Text box with your mouse, and the soft keyboard should open:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141378/is-there-a-popup-soft-keyboard-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: Clicking on text entry boxes in my app or stock apps never displays a soft keyboard.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I found out how to do this on **the Android emulator itself** (Menu, "Settings" App - not the settings of the emulator outside). All you need to do is:

open settings app -> Language & Input -> Go to the "Keyboard & Input Methods -> click Default

This will bring up a Dialog in which case you can then disable the Hardware Keyboard by switching the hardware keyboard from on to off. This will disable the Hardware keyboard and enable the softkeyboard.

Comment: This is actually the best way to do it since it allows you to use your physical keyboard for input while at the same time showing the soft keyboard!

Comment: My emulator has no menu, only the window with my app running, where is "settings"? Android Studio comes with "File | Settings", but that's not the one.

Comment: No one said anything about a menu button, Setting is the applications, has nothing to do with android studio. @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Comment: This is great! Please do this in **the emulator itself; in the emulator itself; in the emulator itself; in the emulator itself; in the emulator itself; in the emulator itself;**

Comment: This is unclear, as the **emulator itself** has a toolbar for controlling the **emulator itself** (with controls like power, volume up and down, rotate device, camera, etc).  You go to Android Settings inside the running Android image on the emulator, not the **emulator itself**.

Answer (score 40):

Here are the steps:

- => Settings
- => Language and Input
- => Default
- => Hardware Physical Keyboard
- => off to turn on the On Screen Keyboard

[image: Settings =>Language and Input]

[image: Select Default]

[image: Hardware Physical Keyboard => off]

Answer (score 35):

If you're using AVD manager add a hardware property Keyboard support and set it to false.

That should disable the shown keyboard, and show the virtual one.

Comment: I am using the AVD manager, and I'm intrigued by your idea, but (hilariously) every time I try to do it, it resets itself!  I click New... Hardware property, select Keyboard Support, change the value to 'no', click edit/create, but when I edit it again or get info: Hardware Keyboard = yes!  Ha!  I can't express how sublime I find the Android emulator.

Comment: However, manually changing the value of hw.keyboard in ~/.android/avd/whatever.avd/config.ini caused the setting to stick, and that does indeed make the onscreen keyboard visible.  Yay!  Thanks, Doctor!

Comment: Is it possible to have hw.keyboard=no but still be able to use your keyboard to send keystrokes to emulator somehow? When I set hw.keyboard=no, I have to type everything using the android keyboard (tedious for testing). I am testing this on Linux.

Comment: In my version, there is a checkbox "Hardware Keyboard Present" in emulator properties. Unchecking the option solved the case for me. Note: I'm not answering to miha. the hardware keyboard is still disabled.

Comment: @miha Leave Hardware Keyboard enabled in the AVD. Just disabled it in the Language & Input settings on the emulator. That will show the soft keyboard and let you type on the hardware keyboard at the same time.

Comment: @Locutus there is no way to do that on latest 4.x nor 5.0

Comment: @miha Settings > Language & input > Current keyboard > Hardware Switch ON. I just tested it on Android Lollipop and it works. It will show Android software keyboard and the hardware keyboard also will be available.

Answer (score 9):

Settings > Language & input > Current keyboard > Hardware Switch ON.

This option worked.

Answer (score 4):

**Settings > Language & input > Current keyboard > Hardware Switch ON.** 

It allows you to use your physical keyboard for input while at the same time showing the soft keyboard.
I just tested it on Android Lollipop and it works.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, with Lollipop these are the steps I followed to show soft keyboard:

1. Settings > Language & Input;
2. under "Keyboard & input methods" label, select "Current Keyboard";
3. A Dialog named "Change Keyboard" appears, switch ON "Hardware", then select "Choose keyboards";
4. another Dialog appears, switch ON the "Sample Soft Keyboard". Here you get an alert about the possibility that keyboard will store everything you write, also passwords. Give OK;
5. Repeat above steps in order to show "Change Keyboard" Dialog again, here the new option "Sample Soft Keyboard" is available and you can select it.

NOTE: after that, you might experience problems in running you app (as I had). Simply restart the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit your virtual device using AVD.
2. Press the "show advance setting" button to show more option scroll
   down to the bottom and check "Enable keyboard input" press "finish" button
   at the bottom corner of your window
3. then start the emulator device that you just set up.
4. inside the emulator,  go to the "Settings" -> "Language & Input"
5. and in the "Keyboard & Input Methods" -> "Default" then "choose
   input method" is shown
6. and switch off "Hardware Physical Keyboard" toggle button

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the new version of NOX app. Software keyboard doesn't work after switching to it in settings. To fix this, I installed Gboard using the Play Market.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tools > AVD Manager > Click on ▾ on the Respective Emulator and > Wipe Data and Restart, will solve the problem on New Android Studio.