# how to show softkeyboard on android lollipop emulator

Tags: android, input, android-emulator, keyboard

before android 5.0, there were [work arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238769/how-can-i-make-the-android-emulator-show-the-soft-keyboard) available to show the software keyboard while still being able to input with your real keyboard.

but since lollipop, android 5.0, those work arounds do not work anymore.

is there any way that you can develop experiencing the full impact of reduced screen state by having the software keyboard, while still being able to use your actual keyboard to type in those awful URLS you have to test?

my complex work around is to "paste" things in the emulator with a [little script](https://github.com/gcb/AdbPaste). but i'm hopping for something simpler, and more importantly, that i can use on somebody else's workstation without having to set up adb and such.

Comment: this should me moved to the Android sub site.. but i can't flag it for move myself.