# How to remove soft keypad from the Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I'm a newbie for **Android Application** Development, I just started off with a very basic app on Android Studio, firstly I launched Emulator from the AVD manager, the Emulator popped up with frame and when I unchecked "Device Frame" & launched again,

[image]

now my question is how do I get rid off the soft keypad(Dark Gray) on the right?

by the way I've tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18627515/1463551), but no luck so far any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, try upgrading android studio to 2.0+ (currently in preview), you'll find a smother and better emulator

> Go to settings
>
> Language and Keyboard
>
> Uncheck "**Android keyboard**" and also check other stuff and uncheck those too